# Using WP_Query() to check if a post exists by slug

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am writing a 404.php for wordpress. I have the plugin 'rolescoper' installed, and some pages require the user be logged in to view.  Rolescoper doesn't offer any way to distinguish between a page not found (404) and a permission denied (403).

I've been able to build this functionality into my pages using the following code:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query ( 'pagename=' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
$is_valid_page = ! empty ( $the_query -> queried_object -> post_title );
```

But, surprisingly, the same method does does not work for posts:

```
$args = array (
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'name' => str_replace ( "/", "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] )  
);

$the_post_query = new WP_Query ( $args );
$is_valid_post = ! empty ( $the_post_query -> queried_object -> post_title );
```

When I do a var_dump on `$the_post_query` i get something that shows 0 results found. I am sure that the page I'm checking for exists.

Any idea how to use `wp_query()` to query for a post by slug?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use something like the `get_page_by_path()` function: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path -- this will work with Posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging through the docs, I found that Rolescoper provided a nice function, `is_restricted_rs()`, for solving this problem:

```
//get the slug requested
$slug = $_SERVER [ 'REQUEST_URI' ];

//First check if it's a page and restricted
$page_id = get_page_by_path ( $slug )->ID;
$page_restricted = is_restricted_rs ( $page_id );

//Then check if it's a post and restricted
$args = array(
  'name'        => $slug,
  'post_type'   => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'numberposts' => 1
);

$my_posts = get_posts($args);

if ( $my_posts ) {
   $post_id = $my_posts[0]->ID;
}

$post_restricted = is_restricted_rs ( $post_id );

//then set $content_restricted for use below
$content_restricted = $post_restricted || $page_restricted;
```

Answer (score 0):

The rolescoper plugin has become defunct and we developed a solution which does not require any external plugin. Instead, we added some code to our theme and added a custom field to each page that we wanted to restrict access to.

This isn't as robust as rolescoper was, but for our use case it was perfect. We have only a few user classes and so I just hardcode the different classes and that's enough for us. I'm sure a similar solution could be used for more complex cases, especially if you expanded on the custom UI code.

I happened to name the field "dhamma_perms" but you could name it anything you want:

```
  function is_restricted() {
      return item_restricted(get_post(), wp_get_current_user());
  }
  
  function item_restricted($page, $user) {
      $dhamma_perms = get_post_meta($page->ID, "dhamma_perms", true);
      $requires_os = $dhamma_perms == "oldstudents";
      $requires_worker = $dhamma_perms == "workers";
      if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        return $requires_os || $requires_worker;
      } else if (get_userdata($user->ID)->user_login == "oldstudent") {
        return $requires_worker;
      } else {
        //dhammaworkers and all named users have full read access
        return false;
      }
  }
```

I then modified any page which could be restricted to have code like this at the top:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if (is_restricted()) : ?>
    <?php show_404(); ?> //I just pasted the full content of our 404 page into a function. The 404 page shows a faux-403 page (WP doesn't have real 403 pages) if the content exists but is restricted. 
<?php else: ?>
    //show normal page stuff
```

I also modified the header.php to have a proper title for 404 and 403 pages:

```
<?php if (is_restricted()) : ?>
  <title> <?php echo "Login Required " . get_theme_mod('dhamma_title_separator') . " " . get_bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
<?php else: ?>
  <title><?php wp_title( get_theme_mod('dhamma_title_separator'), true, "right" ); bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
<? endif; ?>
```

Finally, I added a custom UI to posts and pages so it's easy to select permissions:

```
//Register the permissions metabox for posts and pages
function add_perms_box( $post ) {
   $screens = [ 'post', 'page', 'wporg_cpt' ];
   foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {
      add_meta_box(
         'dhamma_perms_box', // Unique ID
         'Permissions',      // Box title
         'perms_box_html',   // Content callback, must be of type callable
         $screens            // Post type
      );
   }
}

function perms_box_html() {
   $value = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "dhamma_perms", true);
   ?>
   <select name="dhamma_perms" id="dhamma_perms" class="postbox">
      <option value="public" <?php selected($value, 'public');?>>Public</option>
      <option value="oldstudents" <?php selected($value, 'oldstudents');?>>Old Students Only</option>
      <option value="workers" <?php selected($value, 'workers');?>>Dhamma Workers Only</option>
   </select>
   <?php
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_perms_box');

function dhamma_meta_save( $post_id ) {
   // Checks save status
   $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
   $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );

   // Exits script depending on save status
   if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision ) {
      return;
   }

   // Checks for input and sanitizes/saves if needed
   if( isset( $_POST[ 'dhamma_perms' ] ) ) {
       update_post_meta( $post_id, 'dhamma_perms', $_POST[ 'dhamma_perms' ] );
   }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'dhamma_meta_save' );
```

This created a new dropdown on each page and post for us:

[image]

I hope this is helpful for anyone else trying to get some simple permissions on a wordpress site!